# Fazer com que um site não execute em nenhuma versão do IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho um site que não deve ser executado em nenhuma versão do *IE*, quando tentarem abrir a url quero que apareça um *background-image* que eu vou montar falando que meu site não e suportado no *IE*.

Isso e possível fazer?

Coloquei esta solução em meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function msieversion() {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        // Se for o IE, retorna a versão
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
            return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)));      
        else
            // Se estiver usando outro navegador, retorna 0                 
            return 0;

       return false;
    }

    var IE = msieversion();

    if (IE !== 0) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTXDZ.jpg')";
        // Fazer algo a mais aqui ...
    } else {
        // O usuário usa outro navegador
    }
</script>
```

e funcionou porem não da forma que eu queria veja a imagem de como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de que somente aparece-se o background e mais nada queria que como se meu site deixa-se de existir no ie

Comment: Qual a razão de quereres bloquear o IE? algo que não funciona?

Comment: nao so isso e horrivel trabalhar com esse navegador por mais que vc tente nunca vai ficar 100% e nao tenho tempo a perder com ele quando e um navegador que menos de 1% da população ultiliza e meu site e voltado para jogos logo abusa de efeitos e fazer isso funcionar no ie e um inferno

Comment: Kirito, o código que postei funcionou no teu caso?

Comment: amigo vou testar jaja e que to no trabalho e me enrolei em outra coisa aqui

Comment: Cara, melhor rodar bugando do que não rodar e aparecer um erro desses na cara do seu visitante. Ainda mais quando o cara usa IE, convenhamos, quem usa IE não tem conhecimento básico de TI (não vai instalar outro navegador)... ou seja, -1 visitante/cliente pra você.

Comment: @DiegoMoreira e amigo faz sentido e que como meu site e voltado para o publico gamer nao acho necessidade de ultilizar o exlorer porque ate entao eu publico alvo sao jogadores logo pode ate ser que tenha um que use o ie mais eu acho dificil

Comment: o motivo que apresenta é de um amadorismo lamentável..  o único que perde é vc mesmo. Se escrever um código conciso, incluindo bom senso em saber usar scripts prontos como plugins de jquery, não terá problemas com browser algum..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de detectar o navegador, é verificando a propriedade *user-agent*, como propõe [está resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999868/1608936):

```js
function msieversion() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    // Se for o IE, retorna a versão
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)));      
    else
        // Se estiver usando outro navegador, retorna 0                 
        return 0;

   return false;
}

var IE = msieversion();

if (IE !== 0) {
    document.getElementById("bgImagem").style.display = "inline";
    // Fazer algo a mais aqui ...
} else {
    // O usuário usa outro navegador
}
```

```css
#bgImagem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -5000;
}
```

```html
<div align="center"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTXDZ.jpg" style="display: none;" id="bgImagem"></div>
```

Comment: amigo nao a div pode ser colocada em qualquer lugar so meu codigo

Comment: @Kirito Não entendi o que você quis dizer, não funcionou?

Comment: ss nao estava funcionando mexi aqui e deu certo brigadao pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Cara essa abordagem fere conceitos da própria Web.Você tá falando de 1% de quanto? **1% de 10 vai lá mas 1% de 10k é outra néh!** Levando em consideração **Progressive Enhacement** a pegada seria identificar o **objeto** que a version do browser não é compatível, porque se não amigo você teria que fechar a porta pra todos.

**Quem te garante que o browser que o cara tá usando é compatível com alguma feature do seu website**?

E pra isso, já criaram uma **library js** modo mamãe que se chama **Modernizr** você prove **fallback** simples de css se for o caso ou com apenas um if/else você faz o que quer, sem precisar essa abordagem de 1990 que não te garante muita coisa.
[Link da documentação traduzida filé](http://www.andrebuzzo.com.br/bibliotecaModernizr/)

E lembre-se use sempre code open-source!! rsrsr